# Strange vim warnings

Tags: macos, vim

I'm new to vim, but have been doing my best to get it working reasonably well. However, at some point I started getting this whenever I open VIM:

```
!  <D-v>         <C-R>*
i  jk          * <Esc>
```

I then `<enter>` and get on with my work, but I can't seem to find any documentation on what exactly vim is complaining about. Any insights are appreciated!
Running vim 8.0.515 on xterm/iterm2/macOS Sierra.

Edit: this is my .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible              " required

set splitright
filetype off                  " required
set title
set encoding=utf-8

"split navigations
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>

" numbers
set nu 

" language
set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8
language messages en_US.UTF-8

" remap jk to escape
inoremap jk <esc>

inoremap 
" set leader to ,
let mapleader=","

" nerdtree
inoremap <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
vnoremap <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" save
vnoremap <leader>w <esc>:w<cr>
inoremap <leader>w <esc>:w<cr>
nnoremap <leader>w :w<cr>

" save and quit
vnoremap <leader>q <esc>:wq<cr>
inoremap <leader>q <esc>:wq<cr>
nnoremap <leader>q :wq<cr>

" open .vimrc
vnoremap <leader>v <esc>:e ~/.vimrc<cr>
inoremap <leader>v <esc>:e ~/.vimrc<cr>
nnoremap <leader>v :e ~/.vimrc<cr>

" open supercollider.snippets
vnoremap <leader>s <esc>:e  ~/.vim/mysnippets/UltiSnips/supercollider.snippets<cr
inoremap <leader>s <esc>:e ~/.vim/mysnippets/UltiSnips/supercollider.snippets<cr>
nnoremap <leader>s :e ~/.vim/mysnippets/UltiSnips/supercollider.snippets<cr>

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" plugins
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'supercollider/scvim'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
syntax on

let g:sclangTerm = "open -a iTerm.app" 

let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["/Users/kennethflak/mysnippets"]
" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
let g:airline_theme='term'
let g:NERDTreeNotificationThreshold = 500
```

Comment: Vim is not complaining about anything. What you see is the output of a `:map` command that's lost somewhere in your config. See `:help :map`.

Comment: Thanks @romainl! Been reading through the map help file, but still can't figure out what the issue is. The second line seems straightforward, I remapped esc to jk, but the D-v combo is strange, I can't find it anywhere in my .vimrc, and when I hit it the only thing it does it delete current line before entering visual mode, it certainly doesn't seem to map to Ctrl-R. Is there a way to suppress these messages?

Comment: That "message" is *not* a "message" in Vim's acceptance of the term. It's the output of a command. If you don't want that output, don't execute the command. Simple. Now, show us your config if you really want help.

Comment: Awrighty, have added my .vimrc to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dangling (misplaced) 'innoremap' on the line just after `innoremap jk <esc>` which is causing it to echo that on vim launch.

Comment: Well spotted! Thanks a lot!